# DOM : Display div when it's in the view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I have a lot of `div` elements `(ex: 4000)`. So, the first time only the first `div` has `display: block` others have `display: none`. And every `div` has different heights.

```
<div id="maincontainer">
   <div class="child" style="height:300px;display:block;">page1</div>
   <div class="child" style="height:400px;display:none;">page2</div>
   <div class="child" style="height:200px;display:none;">page2</div>
   <div class="child" style="height:100px;display:none;">page2</div>
   <div class="child" style="height:500px;display:none;">page2</div>
   <div class="child" style="height:600px;display:none;">page2</div>
   <div class="child" style="height:500px;display:none;">page2</div>
   <div class="child" style="height:100px;display:none;">page2</div>
   <div class="child" style="height:400px;display:none;">page2</div>
</div>
```

I want to do something like this. When I scroll down I want to display the second element (which is in the view) and this goes on for the last `div element`. Can anyone explain me how to do this thing?

Comment: A library like [this](https://github.com/terwanerik/ScrollTrigger) could help a lot

Comment: I'll check this out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a scroll event to the container and when it hits the bottom you load the next element.

```
const element = document.querySelector('#maincontainer');

element.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
   if (this.scrollHeight - this.scrollTop - this.clientHeight <= 0) {
     // load next element here
   }
}
```

Working example here, also working if you add dynamic elements: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLJpad

Comment: Can you provide a snipet ? This would be helpful for others too.

Comment: Updated my answer, is this what you want?

Comment: Hi @emcee22 . I have a question. What if I add a new div when clicking a button. This is not working on that condition. How can I achieve that? Do you have any suggesiton?

Comment: Hi, then you should get the list of elements inside the scroll function

Comment: @MariSelvan check out the codepen link, I've updated the code

Comment: It's not working after you reach the last element and click the button. And if I add some element in the middle then also this logic goes wrong. @emcee22

Comment: I have an idea  @emcee2. What about just visible the content in the viewport and above and below elements. I don't know how to implement this one. Can you help me with this..

Comment: This is a totally different question, you should open a new one. Cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471469/dom-show-elements-only-presents-in-the-view-port?noredirect=1#comment99533962_56471469

Comment: Hi, @emcee22. I created a new question. Can you look into that?