# DOM : Show elements only presents in the view port?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I want to show elements only in the viewport. For example, I have the below model dom.

```
<div id="maincontainer">
 <div class="child" style="height:300px;display:block;">page1</div>
 <div class="child" style="height:400px;display:none;">page2</div>
 <div class="child" style="height:200px;display:none;">page2</div>
 <div class="child" style="height:100px;display:none;">page2</div>
 <div class="child" style="height:500px;display:none;">page2</div>
 <div class="child" style="height:600px;display:none;">page2</div>
 <div class="child" style="height:500px;display:none;">page2</div>
 <div class="child" style="height:100px;display:none;">page2</div>
<div class="child" style="height:400px;display:none;">page2</div>
```

And the style property for that

```
#maincontainer {
  height: 500px;
}
```

Now the viewport of the `maincontainer` is `500px`. When I scroll I want to show only the elements within the `maincontainer`(display block elements within the `maincontainer`). How can I do this? Anyone, please help me with this problem.

Comment: What do you mean? The browser already will hide things outside of it's browser window size.

Comment: I want elements outside the viewport will have display:none property.

Comment: And how do you plan on showing them again? If there is just one item in the list that's say 1000px and your window is exactly 1000px... you can't scroll, but the others are "hidden"... so they can't ever appear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to display elements which are above and below of the current element. I think this will work

Comment: Look at the Intersection Observer API, I have implemented plenty of those situations with it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Do you have any code-pen examples? Please provide some. This will be helpful for me.